# Missing OpenCV Dlls in Extracted bin folder

Tags: c++, opencv, dll

I extracted opencv 3.0 but the bin folder has only has 6 files from which 4 are dlls... All the opencv download tutorial videos I have watched show the folder having way more dll files. I don't even see the highgui.dll
Does this mean something is wrong?? [bin folder content](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QsvBX.png)

And do I need to cmake the source files to work with opencv or is just to see the examples...

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

They are all now in opencv_world300.dll

Just include that in your project and make sure all the libs are referenced in your linker settings and it'll work

Comment: 300 and 300d for debug